# Android compose: how to position icons in the margins of a text in a row?

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, row, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to have a card with the following layout:

- an icon on the left;
- text in the center;
- an icon to the right;

The icons must always be present regardless of the length of the text:
[image]

In this regard I wrote the following code:

```
fun test() {
Card(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
) {
    Row(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(all = 16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back")
        Text("Title", textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete, contentDescription = "Delete")
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that if the text is too long, then the last icon "disappears":
[image]

A solution could be to use `Modifier.width (x.dp)` on the text, but in this case how do I set the value of `x` to cover the maximum possible width within the icons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can apply `Modifier.weight(1f)` to the `Text` composable.

Something like:

```
Row(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(30.dp)
){
    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back")
    Text("Title", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) // Fill this with remaining space available
    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete, contentDescription = "Delete")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can make this spacing arrangement with distributed weights directly.
I've added each icon weight 1 and rest of the space to title.
Or you may also use ConstraintLayout for this, but row with weights works fine too.

```kotlin
Row(
    Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back"
    )
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(8f),
        text = "Title",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
        contentDescription = "Delete"
    )
}
```